# Every Other List Item in a Certain Class

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to make every other list item in a list with a particular class have no margin. I have dound what method I should use:

```
ul>li:nth-child(even){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

But the thing is, that code will make every list's even items have no margin when I just want lists with a certain class to have no margins.

I've tried adding the class to the rule like this:

```
.crpw ul>li:nth-child(even){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

But that doesn't work. Can anyone enlighten me as to how I would achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean `.crpw>li:nth-child(even)` if it has that class you don't need to say `ul` as it is already selecting that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already selecting the element with `.crpw` you do not need to use `ul` after. If you use that it will look for the next `ul` within `.crpw`.

So you would just use:

```
.crpw > li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/F95ZH/1/)